# CLLocationManager delegate not called in ios 10 swift 3 simulator

Tags: swift3, ios10

The CLLocationManager delegate never gets called. Here is my code:

```
  import UIKit
  import CoreLocation
  class LocationController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        // ask permission - NOT NECESSARY IF YOU ALREADY ADDED NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription IT UP INFO.PLIST
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        // when in use foreground
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else{
        print("set up location access  in info.plist")
    }
   }

   private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("locationmanager got called")
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
   }
  }
```

info.plist settings:

[image: info.plist]

My Simulator settings:

[image: simulator setting]

Comment: I don't see any duplicate in the code, there is only one func locationManager. I don't understand can you explain?

Comment: Yes this answered the question. Thank you Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the location after starting application? In menu: Debug / Location / ...
Or change the default location (on your last screenshot)

Comment: Allow Location Simulation setting was already checked by default. I did not set a default location at any time. Please let me know what settings if any are wrong?

Comment: After replying to you, I went go back and set the default location to current location and tried again. It still does not work.

Comment: When running a simulator you can select location from the menu, like I said above Debug / Location / ... . By default it can be none, so you wouldn't get notifications.

Comment: Just now solved the problem from another thread that answered this. I had to change delegate method to: func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

} since I am using Swift 3.0